# Using custom Qt plugin in Android application

Tags: android, c++, plugins, qml, qt5

In my cross-platform application, I use custom-made qt geoservices plugin, and it works fine in desktop application. But, as soon as I try to use it in Android app, [QML PLugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-plugin.html) object fails to load my plugin, but still can load qt built-in geoservices plugins like **here** or **osm**. Yet, I can load my plugin manually via [QPluginLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html):

```
QPluginLoader loader("libplugins_geoservices_libqtgeoservices_empty.so");
if (loader.load()) {
    qDebug() << loader.metaData();
    loader.unload();
}
loader.setFileName("libplugins_geoservices_libqtgeoservices_osm.so");
if (loader.load()) {
    qDebug() << loader.metaData();
    loader.unload();
}
```

with output:

```
QJsonObject({"IID":"org.qt-project.qt.geoservice.serviceproviderfactory/5.0","MetaData":{"Experimental":false,"Features":["OfflineMappingFeature"],"Keys":["empty"],"Provider":"empty","Version":100},"className":"EmptyGeoServiceProviderFactory","debug":false,"version":328961})
QJsonObject({"IID":"org.qt-project.qt.geoservice.serviceproviderfactory/5.0","MetaData":{"Experimental":false,"Features":["OnlineMappingFeature","OnlineGeocodingFeature","ReverseGeocodingFeature","OnlineRoutingFeature","OnlinePlacesFeature"],"Keys":["osm"],"Provider":"osm","Version":100},"className":"QGeoServiceProviderFactoryOsm","debug":false,"version":328961})
```

QML code:

```
Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
//        name: "empty" // doesn't work
    name: "osm" // works fine
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(availableServiceProviders) // outputs: "here,osm,mapbox"
}
```

I use Qt 5.5 for both desktop and android builds.